# Remote Python Interpreter Docker-Compose

Tags: docker, pycharm, docker-compose

**Environment**

- MAC OS HIGH SIERRA 10.13.3
- Docker-Compose 1.18.0
- Docker 17.12.0
- Pycharm Professional License Build #PY-173.4301.16, built on January
  11, 2018

**Goal**

Run Python interpreter from docker-compose containers.

I tried following [these steps](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/docker-compose.html) but I get the following error:

```
com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.DockerException: Mounts denied: {errno = [EACCES]; call = getattrlist; label = /private/var/root/Library }
```

I don't really know how to move on from this point.

Pycharm has the appropriate plugins, and Docker has the file `/private` in file sharing. Because the containers are located in `/opt` I do run Pycharm with root privileges, don't know if that might be of effect on anything.